# linear transformation of finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional real vector spaces and $T\colon V\to W$ be linear.

(a)Prove that if $\dim(V) < \dim(W)$, then $T$ cannot be onto.

(b)Prove that if $\dim(V) > \dim(W)$, then $T$ cannot be one to one

I'm having trouble understanding how to even begin this question. Since we know that every linear transformation is a matrix transformation then...

$AV=W$, but by matrix multiplication, $A$ times $V$ will always result in the same number of vectors in $V$. So how is it possible for a transformation to result in more vectors than it began with?

Comment: For (b), prove the contrapositive. If $T$ is injective, what can you say about the set $\left\{T(v_1), \ldots ,T\left(v_{\dim(V)}\right)\right\}$, where $\left\{v_1, \ldots , v_{\dim(V)}\right\}$ is a base of $V$?

Comment: I see you're a new user and that you haven't accepted any answers so far. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt An unescaped `<` does that. It's interpreted as the start of a HTML tag ;)

Comment: For part a, consider a basis of $V$ and then the image of that basis under $T$ in $W$. Can this set of vectors in the image span all of $W$? If $T$ is onto, this set of vectors should span $W$ (why?).

Comment: Do you know the dimension theorem, sometimes called the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahha. I see I should start checking the edits when noticing fishy things.

Comment: @BenWest How does the rank nullity theorem relate to this problem? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, rank-nullity says $\dim(V)=\dim(\ker T)+\dim(\operatorname{im} T)$. So if $\dim V<\dim W$, you have

$$\dim(\operatorname{im} T)\leq\dim V<\dim W,$$
 so $\dim(\operatorname{im} T)<\dim W$. So $T$ cannot be onto.

Suppose now $\dim V>\dim W$. Since $\operatorname{im} T$ is a subspace of $W$, $\dim(\operatorname{im} T)\leq\dim W$. Then by rank-nullity
$$
\dim V=\dim(\ker T)+\dim(\operatorname{im} T)>\dim W\geq\dim(\operatorname{im} T)
$$
so that $\dim(\ker T)>0$. Now just recall that $T$ is one-to-one iff $\ker T$ is trivial, iff $\dim(\ker T)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(e_i)$ be a basis for $V$

$Ran T$ is spanned by $(T e_i)$; thus $\dim Ran T\leq\dim V$. It follows that if T is onto, $\dim W = \dim Ran T \leq \dim V$.

On the other hand, if $T$ is injective, it is not hard to show that $(T e_i)$ is linearly independent. It follows that $\dim W\geq \dim Ran T=\dim V$.